# jQuery autocomplete and parsing received JSON

Tags: jquery

JavaScript code of doing ajax request

```
$('#search-field').autocomplete({source: 'url/of/autocomplete'});
```

It worked perfectly until I changed JSON structure. It used to return

```
["anything","something","super value"]
```

Now it (server) returns a bit complex JSON

```
[{"title":"some-title","link":"/searc?q=some-title"}, {"title":"some-title2","link":"/searc?q=some-title2"}]
```

Well, it's not shown now. It's working but the values (title) are not shown obviously.

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: can you post your datasource look like i mean is it coming from server?

Comment: Yes, it coming from server, it's an ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using a AJAX returned data so the source attribute should be an function and you have to add a new attribute for when it's selected. When you receive the data you need to store it in a global variable, and then you take its value in the other function:

```
 $('#search-field').autocomplete({source: function(){
       jQuery.post('url', data, function(dataReceived){globalVariable = dataReceived; }, 'json');
   },

   select: function(event, ui) { 
      var local = globalVariable[ui.item];
      // work with the local variable.
 }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to rename "title" to "label" and "link" to "value". That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot see your code, let's assume that `[{"title":"some-title","link":"/searc?q=some-title"}, {"title":"some-title2","link":"/searc?q=some-title2"}]` is your datasource. That being said, this is how I would go about it...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var dataSource= [{"title":"some-title","link":"/searc?q=some-title"}, {"title":"some-title2","link":"/searc?q=some-title2"}];

    $('#search-field').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
        var filterResults = $.map(dataSource, function(item) {
            if(item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) != -1 || item.link.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) != -1){
             return item;
         }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    });
      response(filterResults);
     }
    }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item)
{
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append($("<a></a>").html("Title: " + item.title + ", Link: " + item.link))
        .appendTo(ul);
};
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hUE9M/131/

Going about it in this method, you are able to search both the "title" & "link" properties.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

keep the old JSON structure and experiment first with what works

Comment: this is more of a comment then an answer :/

Comment: give a man a fish and he eats for a day teach a man to fish and he can feed himself for life

Comment: give a man a fish and them will be surprised: "Why did they give a fish? I'm just staying at a bus stop and waiting for a bus".